# The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax, substring

I want to a take the substring of a value in a column " 2010-11-10 11:59:00" to  "2010-11-10":

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(DATETIME, export_date, 105)),0,15),101) 
  FROM TABLE
```

I have written the following query, but it is not resulting this error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-11-10 11:59:00',101)))
```

Output

```
2010-11-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Hey. How are you. These questions come up in various formats, and it is always handy to know the conversion tricks. X-)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT substring(convert(varchar(15),convert(varchar(15), export_date, 105)),0,11) from

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!